# How to set timeout for TestNG's @BeforeSuite method thru a Listener class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I would like to set some timeout for a BeforeSuite method through a Listener class. I could not find help for this. (Am using Selenium WebDriver)
I have so many test suites, we've set timeout for each of the tests & would like to restrict the time for the BeforeSuite method as well.
I would like to set it through a Listener instead of adding it in each suite.

```
@BeforeSuite(groups = {"aa-bb-cc"})
    public void abcdef(ITestContext context) throws Exception {
        ....}
@AfterSuite(groups = {"aa-bb-cc"})
    public void cleanup() {
        quitDriver();
    }
```

How can I set timeouts using a listener for the above 2methods (instead of hardcoding the timeout like @BeforeSuite(groups = {"aa-bb-cc"}, timeOut=600000))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer2

[Documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers), 
[Java Doc IAnnotationTransformer2](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/IAnnotationTransformer2.html)

> Use this interface instead of IAnnotationTransformer if you want to
>   modify any TestNGannotation besides @Test.

You will need to override method having parameter IConfigurationAnnotation

```
@Override
public void transform(IConfigurationAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,
        Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {

    annotation.setTimeOut(10);

}
```